# Asymptotic solution of a system of ODEs

Tags: differential-equations, series-expansion, asymptotics

I have the following system of Ordinary Differential Equations (ODEs) together with initial values

```
ode = {-4 * (1 + u * a[u]) * f'[u] == (a[u]^3 + 1/4 * a[u] + (3 a[u]^2 + 1/4) * u * a'[u]) + 2 (a[u] + u * a'[u]) * f[u], 
       a'[u] == 1/2 * u * f'[u], 
       a[0] == -1/2, f[0] == 0}
```

which can be easily solved numerically:

```
{ra, rf} = NDSolveValue[ode, {a, f}, {u, 0, 20}]
```

and asymptotically for $u\rightarrow0$.

```
AsymptoticDSolveValue[odetph, {a[u], f[u]}, {u, 0, 3}]

(* {-(1/2) + u^2/64 + u^3/128, u/16 + (3 u^2)/128 + (3 u^3)/512} *)
```

But I need to know an asymptotic expansion of `a[u]` as $u\rightarrow\infty$. Even the coefficient of the lowest order term $\sim 1/u$ would be very nice to know. Is there a trick to obtain such a solution with MA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach is to introduce the ansatz
$$
f(u)=\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{f_k}{u^k},\qquad a(u)=\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{a_k}{u^k}
$$
which you plug into the ODE and solve for the coefficients. I find
\begin{aligned}
f(u)&=\frac{3}{8}-\frac{1}{u^2}+\frac{3}{2 u^4}-\frac{7}{2 u^8}+\frac{33}{2 u^{12}}+\cdots\\
a(u)&=-\frac{1}{u}+\frac{1}{u^3}-\frac{2}{u^7}+\frac{9}{u^{11}}+\cdots
\end{aligned}

Check:

```
ode[[1 ;; 2]] /. {f -> (3/8 - 1/#^2 + 3/(2 #^4) - 7/(2 #^8) + 33/(2 #^12) &), a -> (-(1/#) + 1/#^3 - 2/#^7 + 9/#^11 &)}
Series[%, {u, ∞, 12}] // Simplify

(* {True, True} *)
```

You can of course add more terms, with symbolic coefficients, and find their correct value by solving the equation order by order. I'm sure you know what I mean but feel free to ask, of course.

The numeric minus the asymptotic solutions differ by

[image]

which is so close to 0 that the numerics overwhelm the error. Might need to increase accuracy to get a meaningful plot...

Comment: Amazing! I was so focused on `AsymptoticDSolve` and why it does not work that I started thinking there is some fundamental obstacle and even did not try to use such an ansatz. Do you know why `AsymptoticDSolve` does not work here? Also, I understood you obtain the solution "by hands". Is there a way to automatise it?

Comment: @yarchik: You asked " Is there a way to automatise it?". Maybe, `SolveAlways` helps with it.

Comment: @user64494 I tried `SolveAlways`, but not all coefficients can be obtained in this way. I am not getting $f_0=3/8$ and $a_1=-1$ in this way.

Comment: @yarchik: `ode = {-4*(1 + u*a[u])*
     f'[u] == (a[u]^3 + 1/4*a[u] + (3 a[u]^2 + 1/4)*u*a'[u]) + 
     2 (a[u] + u*a'[u])*f[u], 
   a'[u] == 1/2*u*f'[u]} /. {a[u] -> Sum[a[k]/u^k, {k, 0, 3}], 
   f[u] -> Sum[f[k]/u^k, {k, 0, 3}], 
   a'[u] -> D[Sum[a[k]/u^k, {k, 0, 3}], u], 
   f'[u] -> D[Sum[f[k]/u^k, {k, 0, 3}], u]};SolveAlways[ode, u]` works for me.

Comment: @user64494 It indeed works, but unless I am missing something, none of these solutions contain the $f_0=3/8$ answer.  I believe that the solutions in the answer are correct. However, the series substitution is not enough to obtain them because it does not care the initial conditions.

Comment: @yarchik: (i) The  initial conditions are given at the origin, the power expansions are at infinity. (ii) Ask AccidentalFourierTransform for these expansions.

Comment: @yarchik The values $(f_0,a_1)=(3/8,-1)$ come from the initial conditions $(f(0),a(0))=(0,-1/2)$. They cannot be determined just by looking at the differential equation, they require specifying initial data as well. For example if you replace your initial conditions by  more general family $(f(0),a(0))=(0,\alpha)$, then $f_0$ becomes $$\frac{1}{32} (4 \alpha  (\alpha -\sqrt{8 \alpha ^2+2})+(4 \alpha  (\sqrt{8 \alpha ^2+2}-3 \alpha )-1) \text{sign}(\alpha )-1)\,.$$

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Thank you. In the meantime I was able to solve the equations analytically. The search series can then be obtained as `AsymptoticSolve[a^2 (2+a u)^2==1+a u,a,{u,Infinity,12}]`